# Adding dynamic views to a UIScrollView

Tags: ios, swift

So I'm trying to clone the Apple weather app. My `ViewHierarchy` looks like this:

`ViewControllerA` contains a `UIScrollView` which in turn contains a `UIView` `(UIView1)` and the `UIView` contains child elements.There is also a button below the `UIScrollView` to add more `UIView` inside the `UIScrollView`.
This `UIViewController` is designed in `IB` using `AutoLayout`.

When I click this button ideally I want to clone the `UIView1` and add it to the `UIScrollView`, to the righthandside end of the `currentView` inside the `UIScrollView`. This is a horizontal scroll function. This is where I am stuck.

What I have tried are the following:
Create a copy of `UIView1` in a `xib` and load that. 
Create a `UIView` programmatically and load that.

In both the cases I'm facing the auto layout constraints issue. When I load the second view, it's overwritten on top of the existing view. 
I can hardcode the frame sizes for the cloned `UIView` and get it to work but obviously that won't work across devices.

So I'm adding constraints - something like this:

```
func buildView(startX:CGFloat, model:CityModel) -> UIView {
    var frame:CGRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, insideScrollView.bounds.width,     insideScrollView.bounds.height)
    var cityView:UIView = UIView(frame: frame)
    var lFrame:CGRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, 100,50)
    var cLabel:UILabel = UILabel(frame: lFrame)
    cLabel.text = model.name
    cLabel.sizeToFit()
    cLabel.textAlignment = .Center

    //cityView.addSubview(cLabel)
    cityView.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor().CGColor
    cityView.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)

    var constX = NSLayoutConstraint(item: cityView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.LeftMargin, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: cityScrollView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.LeftMargin, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)

    cityView.addConstraint(constX)
    return cityView

}
```

The app crashes unable to load this constraint indicating that the view hierarchy does not support this constraint as all the views are not loaded.

I'll keep digging on how to resolve this but any help will be greatly appreciated. Here's my `viewDidLoad` method. Cities is an array of models containing the view data

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    var startScroll = insideScrollView.bounds.width
    if cities != nil {
        for model in cities.cityModels {
            if model.selected {
                cityScrollView.addSubview(buildView(startScroll, model: model))
                startScroll += cityScrollView.bounds.width
            }

        }
    } else {
        var cityModel: CityModel = CityModel(name: "default")
        cityModel.selected = false
        cities = SearchCityModels.sharedInstance
        cities.cityModels.append(cityModel)

    }

}
```

Comment: Look at the method buildView, cityView is not added to the scrollView at this time but you already created constraint with cityView and scrollView, which is not valid. The view has to be in view hierarchy before you can add constraints.

Comment: @k6sandeep dude thanks - Added the constraint after adding the view. Also I was adding the constraint to cityView, changed that to ScrollView and it's now working - though there are conflicting constraints. App is not crashing at least :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posting the answer on behalf of @k6sandeep. I had not loaded the view inside the scrollview but was adding constraints to it. So fixed the same by adding constraints after the insideview was loaded.